# Any suggestions why > operator does not work?

Tags: java, imagej

I'm writing a plugin for ImageJ, in this section of my code I wish to find the index in the array which contains the largest number.

```
int index1 =0;

    for(int k=1; k<array.length; k++)
    {
    IJ.showMessage("array[k] "+array[k]+" value "+value);    

    if (array[k]>value);
        {
                value = array[k];

                index1=k;

        }
    }
```

array[] is a 20 index integer array.

The code compiles and when I run it, the series of message windows say:

1. "array[k] 6037 value 2030"
2. "array[k] 11544 value 6037"
3. "array[k] 12287 value 11544"
4. "array[k] 7369 value 12287"
   and finally:
5. "array[k] 2873 value 7369"

If my > operator is working correctly then why does statement 5 showing the opposite?

Thank you for your time

Bateman

Answer (score 11):

Change

```
if (array[k]>value);
```

To

```
if (array[k]>value)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've obviously been staring at the screen for too long!

Comment: I suggest if you use eclipse (but I guess this is available for netbeans as well), use code formatter, and use the basic code formatter on save action, so for example these mistakes will be visible on saving the code.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary: While I agree about using the code formatter, it would be indented the same way with or without the semi-colon.

Comment: i asume that checkstyle would warn about the empty statement

Comment: @JonSkeet for me the code formatter made separate three lines of "if {;}" out of the code and kept the { code } section.

Comment: @AlexWien yes, it is lot more visible than a single ; sign on the end of the line which is pretty common sight in everybody's code. I have to admit, I haven't seen the problem in the first moment in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hey, you are right, I use "Use blocks in if/while/for/do" always inside "Save Actions".

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ";" in line

> if (array[k]>value) {

the ";" is an empty statement that is executed when the condition is true. The following curly braces block is executed ever.
Use checkstyle plugin in eclipse, this should warn about the empty statement.

Answer (score 3):

You have a trailing ; after your if.